# How can I use a computed function inside a method function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hi I am trying to call a computed function inside a method function.

VueJs Code:

```
<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.isDisabled(0);
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                branch_office_id: null,
                cashier_id: null,
                gross_amount: '',
                released_tickets: '',
                start_ticket: '',
                end_ticket: '',
                z_inform_number: '',
                created_at: '',
                support: null,
                error_end_bill_number_validation: ''
            },
            postsSelected: "",
            branch_office_posts: [],
            cashier_posts: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkEndBillNumber() {
            if(this.form.start_ticket > this.form.end_ticket) {
                this.isDisabled(1);
                this.$awn.alert("El número de boleta inicial no puede ser ", {labels: {success: "Error"}});
            } else {
                this.isDisabled(0);
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isDisabled(value) {
            if(value == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am trying to user isDisabled() function inside checkEndBillNumber() method function but when I do that it says:

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.isDisabled is not a function"

So I wonder how can I use it? how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot pass params in computed function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties as mentioned above are not functions. Hence passing arguments like `isDisabled(value)` wont work. But you can trick it to anonymously accept the value like this

```
computed: {
   isDisabled() {
      return (value) => { 
        if(value == 0) return true;
        else return false;
      }
   }
}
```

This way you don't need a data property.

Comment: That's a neat trick, but does this accomplish caching as well? Which is what the computed properties do and are meant for.  This example here in fact is not useful per se, as it should rather be a plain simple method, not a computed property, I guess. But still this is what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have computed *functions*, but computed *properties*! So you have to store the value you want to use as a parameter in your computed *property* - e.g. in a `data` attribute, and then use that:

```
<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.disabledParam = 0;
        this.isDisabled; // Evaluates to "true" - what do you want with that result?
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                branch_office_id: null,
                cashier_id: null,
                gross_amount: '',
                released_tickets: '',
                start_ticket: '',
                end_ticket: '',
                z_inform_number: '',
                created_at: '',
                support: null,
                error_end_bill_number_validation: ''
            },
            postsSelected: "",
            branch_office_posts: [],
            cashier_posts: [],
            disabledParam: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkEndBillNumber() {
            if (this.form.start_ticket > this.form.end_ticket) {
                this.disabledParam = 1;
                this.isDisabled; // Evaluates to "false" - what to you want to do with that value?
                this.$awn.alert("El número de boleta inicial no puede ser ", {labels: {success: "Error"}});
            } else {
                this.disabledParam = 0;
                this.isDisabled; // Evaluates to "true" - what to you want to do with that value?
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isDisabled() {
            if (this.disabledParam == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Also, please note that your calls to `isDisabled(1)` wouldn't so anything even if you could use them as functions. You should probably do something with the return values of `isDisabled`.
And you do not need computed properties in this way - in your example, you should simply create `isDisabled(value)` as another method and call that. But I guess your code is just an example, not your real code. Computed properties usually are being used as values in your template.

My example code is just there to illustrate how you can pass parameters into the code of computed properties. Besides that, your code has some issues.